# Share internet connection from desktop with no wireless adapter to phone

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I want to share my internet from my desktop to my phone but my desktop doesn't have wireless adapter, how can i achieve that? I am using windows 10 in my desktop..

Comment: You can easily obtain a wireless card for your desktop. I have done that before.  Works fine.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396762/254567 from a previous post.  You might need another NIC either way.  That's how without wireless on the PC.